# write avro data to kafka using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using 'confluent-kafka-python'client to write avro data to a kafka topic.

I've written the data, but when I try to read the data using:
kafka-avro-console-consumer I get an error:

```
 [2017-05-02 13:38:11,387] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:105)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 4
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
```

apparently it cannot decode the data.
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can't connect to the Schema Registry. Are you sure you have it up and running and have the URL and port connect for your consumer?

Try adding the following to your console consumer

--property schema.registry.url=address of your schema registry

Comment: I get the same error even when I am looking at a topic using Landloop. It is recognized that is avro, but when I select the topic I get:

{
  "error_code": 50002,
  "message": "Kafka error: Error deserializing Avro message for id 13"
}

Comment: I've added --property schema.registry.url and it works. Thank you !